# internal keyword in C#

Tags: c#

I have a c# static class that I have declared as internal. I also declared a static property in it. I declared it as public. Now when a public property is encapsulated in an internal class does it limit its scope or not.

Here is a small code snippet:

```
internal static class A
{    
    public static int RollCount
    {
           get { return _rollCount; }
    }

}
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Did you try it out? The intelli-sense will get it right. PS. Yes, it's limited by the class visibility first.

Comment: This would be quicker to try out yourself than to write a question and wait for a response on Stack Overflow, would it not?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> I have a c# static class that I have declared as internal. I also declared a static property in it. I declared it as public. Now when a public property is encapsulated in an internal class does it limit its scope or not.

To be strictly correct, no.  The *scope* of an entity is defined as *the region of program text in which that entity may be referred to by its unqualified name*.  The scope of the property is the same regardless of the accessibility domain of the class; the property's scope includes the body of the class and those of any subclasses.

The question you actually intended to ask was "what is the *accessibility domain* of a public property of an internal class?" The accessibility domain of an entity is the region of program text in which that entity is accessible. The answer to that is "the accessibility domain of a public property of an internal class is the same as the accessibility domain of the class". The accessibility domain of an internal class is the program in which it is declared.

Comment: Thanks Eric, that makes a lot of sense. Thanks everybody else for chipping in with your answers.

Answer (score 6):

A member can't be more visible than the class it's in. It's not an error to have internal or private classes with public members, because then you don't have to edit each member declaration if you want to make the class more visible than it was to begin with.

Comment: Good answer.  It's like having a bunch of open doors behind a closed door.  You can't see or touch the inner door so the accessibility doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 2):

Since your external code will never be able to access A, it will never be able to access A.PayRollCount.

Answer (score 1):

The <strike>*visibility*</strike> *accessibility domain* (not *scope*) of the property is effectively limited by the accessibility domain of the class it is defined in, yes. So when writing code this property is effectively `internal`.

However, there are cases where the `public` access might make a difference: if you pass `typeof(A)` to some code that which cannot normally see `class A`, and that code does reflection on the `Type` object, the property is `public` for purposes of reflection.

Comment: Well if we're going to be picky about scope, let's be picky about visibility too. The *accessibility domain* (not the *visibility*) of the property is a subset of the *accessibility domain* of its enclosing class.  *Visibility* is a function of *overlapping scope*.

Comment: @EricLippert: Thank you for the correction; my terminology can definitely use improvement. I amended the answer to match.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the scope of this method is limited to the containing assembly. In order to call a static method you need to use the containing class and because this class is internal will only be visible inside the assembly it is declared in (unless you use reflection of course).

Answer (score 0):

This can be pretty useful if you want to use the Factory pattern to external users of your code since you can implement an interface as an internal class and then expose it to your friends through a Factory method.

Your code:

```
//Library.dll
namespace Library
{
    using System;
    public static class Factory
    {
        public static IFoo CreateFoo()
        {
            return new Foo();
        }
    }
    public interface IFoo
    {
        void DoSomething();
    }
    class Foo : IFoo
    {
        public void DoSomething()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The internal foos public method is called from another assembly!!");
        }
    }
}
```

Consumer code:

```
//Console.exe
namespace Console
{
    using Library;
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //var foo = new Foo(); Compilation error

            var foo = Factory.CreateFoo();
            foo.DoSomething();
            System.Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```